# Why is the distortion in a non-homogeneous strain described as $\Delta u_i = \displaystyle \sum_j (e_{ij}- \omega_{ij})\Delta x_j$?

Tags: tensor-calculus, elasticity

> When we have a homogeneous strain - which may include both stretching and shear - all of the $e_{ij}$ are constants, and we can write $$u_x = e_{xx}\mathsf x + e_{xy}\mathsf y +e_{xz}\mathsf z\,.\tag{39.9}$$
>
> [...] When the strains are not homogeneous, any piece of the jello may also get somewhat twisted - there will be a local relation. If the distortions are all small, we should have $$\Delta u_i =  \sum_j (e_{ij}- \omega_{ij})\Delta x_j\,,\tag{39.10}$$ where $\omega_{ij}$ is an *anti-symmetric* tensor, $$\omega_{ij}= \tfrac12 (\partial u_j/\partial x_i- \partial u_i/\partial x_j)\,,\tag{39.11}$$ which describes the rotation.

This is excerpted from *Lectures on Physics*' *Elastic Materials*' [*The tensor of strain*](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_39.html#Ch39-S1) by *Feynman*. Here he describes the tensor of strains for both homogeneous and non-homogeneous substances.

I'm not comprehending how he formulated the definition of tensor of strain $e_{ij}$ for non-homogeneous substances.

Why is there $\Delta$ in $(39.10)$ in the distortion $\Delta u_i$ for non-homogeneous substances? It's not there in the distortion $u_x$ of homogeneous substances in $(39.9)$.

And why was it required to add the *anti-symmetric* tensor in the distortion of non-homogeneous substances viz. in $(39.10)\,?$ Is there no *rotation* in the distortion of homogeneous substances?

Comment: for the people not familiar with Feynman's book/who don't have it lying around, can you provide a definition for the symbols he uses? I have a hunch as to what might be happening, but I'd be happy to be sure before writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the distortion in homogeneous strain, there is, as he writes, a linear relation between $u_j$ and $x_i$, so the derivatives $e_{ij}$ are actually constants and we can integrate
$$ \mathrm du_i = \sum_j e_{ij}~\mathrm dx_j $$ 
to give his formula $(39.9)$
$$ u_i = \sum_j e_{ij} x_j $$
For non-homogeneous strain, the derivatives are actually position dependent and we have:
$$ \mathrm du_i = \sum_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}~\mathrm dx_j $$
or for small values of the distortions:
$$ \Delta u_i = \sum_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \Delta x_j $$
If we look at $e_{ij} - \omega_{ij}$ we have the difference between symmetric and antisymmetric part of the gradient of the distortion field, i.e. the derivative, which we can see by evaluating:
$$ e_{ij} - \omega_{ij}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\right)= \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} $$

And yes, I am pretty positive that a homogeneous strain, i.e. a constant derivative of the distortion w.r.t. the coordinates over all the body which is symmetric, is not possible with a rotation. This is, in the end, the polar decomposition theorem applied to the gradient matrix of the displacement field.